# Making Intellisense and syntax for a language in Typescript

Tags: typescript, syntax, intellisense

I have searched **everywhere** for tutorial making intellisense or syntax with typescript but looking at VSCode docs it requires you to make a project in Language support but I want to make a project that gives you an sample code to test with + intellisense +  syntax if you have any resources you can share share or link github repos that solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code includes TypeScript language support but does not include the TypeScript compiler. You can install typescript compiler globally through npm by `npm install -g typescript`.

In your next step you should define Typescript project settings by `tsconfig.json` file. Visual studio code will use this file to instruct IntelliSense.
You can read more here:

- [tsconfig-json docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)
- [tsconfig.json compilerOptions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig)
- [VSC typescript-compiling](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling)